# OpenCv Template Matching - Unexpected masking result

Tags: java, opencv, template-matching

I am trying to match a template with transparency in a scene with OpenCv v3.3.0
I am using the Java example code from [the official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html).

My test case looks like this:

Scene:

[image: Scene]

Template with transparency:

[image: Template]

Template mask (masked the transparency layer to black):

[image: Mask]

Matching result (red border marks the match):
[image: Matching result]

Expected result (red border marks the expected match):
[image: Expected result]

For the matching I am using CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED.
The matching itself works fine with the mask (without the mask I get a wrong possition). But the found region is the same size as the template and it's mask. I expected it to be the size of the masks colored content.

How can I get the expected results (see image)?

Comment: Crop your template to it's real boundingRect, not use the whole image.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent region means that it can match any pixels as long as those pixels are present. So to make OpenCV find only non-transparent pixels, you need to crop the transparent region on your "query image" first.